# In SQL, how do you count if any rows in a group match a certain criteria?

Tags: sql, group-by, count, presto, having

I'm new to SQL, but I have a dataset that has students, their class subjects, and if there was an error in their work. I want to know how many *students* have at least 1 error in any subject. Thus, whether a student has one subject with an error (like students 2 and 3 in the example) or multiple errors (like student 4), they'd be flagged. Only if they have no errors should they be categorized as 'no'.

I know I have to use GROUP BY and COUNT, and I'm thinking I have to use HAVING as well, but I can't seem to put it together. Here's a sample dataset:

```
ID       Rating      Error  
==========================================
 1       English    No         
 1       Math       No         
 2       English    Yes         
 2       Math       No         
 2       Science    No         
 3       English    Yes         
 4       English    Yes        
 4       Math       Yes
```

And the desired output:

```
Error      Count    Percent  
==========================================
 No        1        .25
 Yes       3        .75
```

Comment: first which rdms are you using. second why not try all those, what you  think is necessary and as a tip no having is not needed

Comment: @nbk , I'm using Presto. I'm trying them all but it's not working probably because I'm very new to SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many different ways you can do it, here is one example by using CTE (common table expressions):

```
with t as (
    select
        id,
        case when sum(case when error='Yes' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 'Yes' else 'No' end as error
    from students
    group by id
)
select
    error,
    count(*),
    (0.0 + count(*)) / (select count(*) from t) as perc
from t
group by error
```

basically, inner query (`t`) is used to calculate error status for each student, outer query calculates error distribution/percentage numbers

Answer (score 0):

There are several useful [functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html) you can use:

> `bool_or(boolean) → boolean` - Returns `TRUE` if any input value is `TRUE`, otherwise FALSE.
> `if(condition, true_value, false_value)` - Evaluates and returns `true_value` if condition is true, otherwise evaluates and returns `false_value`.

`select count(distinct id)` - to count distinct ids.

```sql
with dataset (ID,Rating,Error) as (
    values (1,'Math','No'),
    (2,'English','Yes'),
    (1,'English','No'),
    (2,'Math','No'),
    (2,'Science','No'),
    (3,'English','Yes'),
    (4,'English','Yes'),
    (4,'Math','Yes')
)

select if(has_error, 'Yes', 'No') Error,
    count(*) Count,
    cast(count(*) as double) / (select count(distinct id) from dataset) Percent
from (
    select bool_or(Error = 'Yes') has_error
    from dataset
    group by id
)
group by has_error;
```

Output:

| Error | Count | Percent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Yes | 3 | 0.75 |
| No | 1 | 0.25 |